# Remove Capybara::Webkit::Driver#browser is deprecated message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

In a feature spec, the following code;

```
browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
browser.clear_cookies
```

raises this deprecation message;

```
[DEPRECATION] Capybara::Webkit::Driver#browser is deprecated.
```

How do I remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By removing that statement.  Some methods on `driver` are being removed from the public API in the next release of capybara-webkit.  Since you've indicated that you were calling clear_cookies on the `browser` object, you can now just call it on the `driver` object.

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.clear_cookies
```

Comment: The code depends on a cookie, so I want to test that it behaves correctly when the cookie is not present.  So I am doing ```  browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser```, then ``` browser.clear_cookies```. If you can suggest a better way to do this, that would be excellent.

Comment: @Obromios  Call clear cookies on the driver - Capybara.current_session.driver.clear_cookies

Comment: That worked fine thank you. If you put up an answer along these lines, I will accept it.